# Dynamically set parameters in SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, ado

I created small method. Input parameters of this method - List with Account Type (Accounts which choose user). Output parameters - is a list with parameters from another table.
Here I don't know how could I set it dynamically.
I tried create a method(Here I need set **accountType IN ...** dynamically **from Ilist item**):

```
        public async Task<IList<AccountInfo>> GetAccountByAccountType(IList<AccountType> item)
        {
            //item
            var parameters = new { (',', item.ToArray()) };

            string query = $"SELECT accountID, accountName, AccountNo, accountType from account_ref " +
                            "where accountType not in (4, 9) and accountType IN(1, 2, 3)";

            var accType = await Connection.QueryAsync<AccountInfo>(query);

            return accType.ToList();
        }
```

My Models:
1st

```
[Table("accountType_ref", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class AccountType
    {
        [Column("accountTypeID"), Key()]
        public int AccountTypeId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column("accountTypeName")]
        public string AccountTypeName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

2nd

```
 [Table("account_ref", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class AccountInfo
    {
        [Column("accountID"), Key()]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column("accountName")]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column("AccountNo")]
        public string AccountNumber
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column("accountType")]
        public int AccountType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Goal: User will turn several or one account type (Already done this method). After that User will get new table based on his choose(this is my method).

Answer (score 0):

Just build up the sql string. And because this is web? Then just dynamic build up the @Params in the sql command text.

So, this shows how you can do this:

```
{
DataTable rst = new DataTable();

string strSQL = "SELECT ID,FirstName, LastName, HotelName FROM tblHotels " + "WHERE ID IN ";
string strParms = "";

SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("", new SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3));

string[] mypvalues = Split(this.TextBox1.Text, ",");
for (var i = 0; i <= mypvalues.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (strParms != "")
        strParms += ",";
    strParms += "@p" + i;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@p" + i, SqlDbType.Int).Value = mypvalues[i];
}
strSQL += "(" + strParms + ")";
cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
da.Fill(rst);
}
```

So we have a string like this

```
accountType IN ()
our value list is this 1, 2, 3
```

So, above becomes this:

```
accountType IN (p0, p1, p2)
```

And we set the parms in a loop, eg:

```
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@p" + i, SqlDbType.Int).Value = mypvalues[i];
```

So, we still get parm safe sql, and we also get strong type defines (integer) for the parameters

Most often don't realize that you can loop + set the parameters for the sql command object before we feed into that the sql. I mean, we could have two for/next loops, but the above does it on one go, and for a small list (say 4-10) then using the above "in some list of (@p0, p1) is rather fine for a short list and a "few" values as you ask.

My c# is not all that great, but the above in vb.net looks like this:

```
   Dim rst As New DataTable

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ID,FirstName, LastName, HotelName FROM tblHotels " &
                           "WHERE ID IN "
    Dim strParms As String = ""

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("", New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3))

    Dim mypvalues() As String = Split(Me.TextBox1.Text, ",")
    For i = 0 To mypvalues.Length - 1
        If strParms <> "" Then strParms += ","
        strParms += "@p" & i
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@p" & i, SqlDbType.Int).Value = mypvalues(i)
    Next
    strSQL += "(" & strParms & ")"
    cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
    da.Fill(rst)
```

At this point, we can shove the resulting data table (rst) into the listview, or datagrid like this:

```
   MyListView1.DataSource = rst
   MyListView1.databind
```